# Can Python be configured to cache sys.path directory lookups?

Tags: python, python-import

We've been doing a lot of benchmarking of Python running over a remote connection.  The program is running offsite but accessing disks on-site.  We are running under RHEL6.  We watched a simple program with strace.  It appears it's spending a lot of time performing stat and open on files to see if they are there.  Over a remote connecting that is costly.  Is there a way to configure Python to read a directories contents once and cache it's listing so it doesn't have to check it again?

Sample Program test_import.py:

```
import random
import itertools
```

I ran the following commands:

```
$ strace -Tf python test_import.py >& strace.out
$ grep '/usr/lib64/python2.6/' strace.out | wc
331    3160   35350
```

So it's looking in that directory roughly 331 times.  A lot of them with results like:

```
stat ( "/usr/lib64/python2.6/posixpath", 0x7fff1b447340 ) = -1 ENOENT ( No such file or directory ) < 0.000009 >
```

If it cached the directory it wouldn't have to stat the file to see if it's there.

Comment: Can you give more information about what files it's looking at?  Are you sure that this is due to module lookups?  Importing a module more than once should use the cached module object in `sys.modules`, so there may not be much to gain if that is the nature of the lookups.

Comment: Thanks for asking for clarification.  I don't think it's about module lookups but they would benefit from a cache as well.  I will add more information to the question.

Comment: What do you mean by a remote connection? Is the computer running the python program on a different computer than the one storing python's packages?

Comment: Yes Nick, that is what I mean.  The program is running offsite but accessing disks on-site.  I will add that information to the question.

Comment: You want it to cache between runs, or during a single run?

Comment: Also, are you married to 2.6? There were some minor improvements in this area in 2.7/3.2, then the whole import system was rewritten (90% in pure Python) in 3.3. You can, for example, easily configure 3.3 to use a .pyc directory on a local disk even if the .py files are somewhere else, and hook it to either ignore or copy any remote .pyc files… but that's a lot harder, if even possible, on 2.6.

Comment: Or… what about using `virtualenv` to create a standalone virtual environment? If your libraries are too big and your local drive too small that may not be an option, but if it is, that should completely avoid the problem.

Answer (score 9):

You can avoid this by either moving to Python 3.3, or replacing the standard import system with an alternative. In the `strace` talk that I gave two weeks ago at PyOhio, I discuss the unfortunate *O(nm)* performance (for *n* directories and *m* possible suffixes) of the old import mechanism; start at [this slide](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/slides/2014-07-pyohio/strace/#id39).

I demonstrate how `easy_install` plus a Zope-powered web framework generates 73,477 system calls simply to do enough imports to get up and running.

After a quick install of `bottle` in a virtualenv on my laptop, for example, I find that exactly 1,000 calls are necessary for Python to import that module and be up and running:

```
$ strace -c -e stat64,open python -c 'import bottle'
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000179           0      1519      1355 open
  0.00    0.000000           0       475       363 stat64
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000179                  1994      1718 total
```

If I hop into `os.py`, however, I can add a caching importer and even with a very naive implementation can cut the number of misses down by nearly a thousand:

```
$ strace -c -e stat64,open python -c 'import bottle'
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000041           0       699       581 open
  0.00    0.000000           0       301       189 stat64
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000041                  1000       770 total
```

I chose `os.py` for the experiment because `strace` shows it to be the very first module that Python imports, and the sooner we can get our importer installed, the fewer Standard Library modules Python will have to import under its old terrible slow regime!

```
# Put this right below "del _names" in os.py

class CachingImporter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.directory_listings = {}

    def find_module(self, fullname, other_path=None):
        filename = fullname + '.py'
        for syspath in sys.path:
            listing = self.directory_listings.get(syspath, None)
            if listing is None:
                try:
                    listing = listdir(syspath)
                except OSError:
                    listing = []
                self.directory_listings[syspath] = listing
            if filename in listing:
                modpath = path.join(syspath, filename)
                return CachingLoader(modpath)

class CachingLoader(object):

    def __init__(self, modpath):
        self.modpath = modpath

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        if fullname in sys.modules:
            return sys.modules[fullname]
        import imp
        mod = imp.new_module(fullname)
        mod.__loader__ = self
        sys.modules[fullname] = mod
        mod.__file__ = self.modpath
        with file(self.modpath) as f:
            code = f.read()
        exec code in mod.__dict__
        return mod

sys.meta_path.append(CachingImporter())
```

This has rough edges, of course — it does not try to detect `.pyc` files or `.so` files or any of the other extensions that Python might go looking for. Nor does it know about `__init__.py` files or about modules inside of packages (which would require running `lsdir()` in sub-directories of the `sys.path` entries). But it at least illustrates that thousands of extra calls can be eliminated through something like this, and demonstrates a direction you might try out. When it cannot find a module, the normal import mechanism simply kicks in instead.

I wonder if there is a good caching importer already available on PyPI or somewhere? It seems like the sort of thing that would have been written a hundreds times already in various shops. I thought that Noah Gift had written one and put it in a blog post or something, but I cannot find a link that confirms that memory of mine.

**Edit:** as **@ncoglan** mentions in the comments, there is an alpha-release backport of the new Python 3.3+ import system to Python 2.7 available on PyPI: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/importlib2 — unfortunately it looks like the questioner is still stuck on 2.6.

Comment: This is super helpful.  Thanks Brandon. We will run some tests with it.

Comment: Eric Snow has an experimental backport of the whole Python 3 import system up on PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/importlib2

Comment: Thanks Nick, we are investigating the problem under Python 2.7 and checking out the library that Eric wrote.

Comment: FYI, given importlib's awesome test suite I'm confident that importlib2 is solid.  I'm only qualifying it as "alpha" because I haven't had a chance yet to give the code one last been-away-from-it-a-while review.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is not exactly what you are looking for but I'll answer anyway :D

There is no cache system for `sys.path` directories but `zipimport` creates an index of the modules inside of the `.zip` file. This index is used to make module lookup faster.

The drawback of this solution is that you cannot use it with binary modules (eg. .so) due to the lack of support in `dlopen()` that is used by Python to load this kind of module.

Other problem is that some modules (like the `posixpath` used on your example) is loaded by CPython interpreter during its bootstrap process.

PS. I hope you remember me at PythonBrasil when I helped you stuff some bags with Disney/Pixar souvenirs :D

Comment: I do remember and thank you for your help then and now. :-)  I appreciate the pointer to zipimport.  You're right it doesn't solve the larger problem but it might help some.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using an importer or zipimport, you should also consider freezing your code.  Freezing will drastically reduce stat calls.

part of Python: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze
third-party:    http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Freezing a rudimentary script dropped stats from 232 to 88.

```
$ strace -c -e stat64,open python2 hello.py
hello
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000011           0       232       161 open
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000011                   232       161 total
$ strace -c -e stat64,open ./hello
hello
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
  -nan    0.000000           0        88        73 open
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000000                    88        73 total
```

You're still susceptible to the number of entries in your sys.path (but that is where importlib2 and its caching would help you).